# Internet Explorer is not executing my script

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

I've made a script that move the images as you, click the next and back button in my website, it works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Opera and Safari, but doesn't work in IE11.

I've already tried putting

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

at the head and also this script before closing :

```
if (typeof(UserAgentInfo) != 'undefined' && !window.addEventListener) 
{ 
    UserAgentInfo.strBrowser=1; 
}
```

none of it works, here is part of my script:

```js
 var slideS = document.querySelector('.slide');
 var slideImg = document.querySelectorAll('.slide img');
 var slideC = document.querySelector('.slideC');
 
 //buttons
 var prevBtn = document.querySelector('#prevBtn');
 var nextBtn = document.querySelector('#nextBtn');
 
 var counter = 1;
 var size = slideC.offsetWidth;
 
 slideS.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
    var counter = 1;
 var size = slideC.offsetWidth;
 
 slideS.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
 
 nextBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
 if (counter >= slideImg.length - 1) return;
 slideS.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
 counter = counter + 1;
 slideS.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
 });
 
 prevBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
 if (counter <= 0) return;
 slideS.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
 counter = counter - 1;
 slideS.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
 });
 

 slideS.addEventListener('transitionend', ()=>{
  if(slideImg[counter].id === 'uClone'){
   slideS.style.transition = "none";
   counter = slideImg.length - 2;
   slideS.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)'; 
  }
  if(slideImg[counter].id === 'pClone'){
   slideS.style.transition = "none";
   counter = slideImg.length - counter;
   slideS.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';   
  }
 });
```

```css
    .slide {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;    
    }
    .slideC {
    width: 768px;
    height: 432px;
    margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    }
      
    .menuBtn:hover{
     color: #6936a3;
    }
    
    #prevBtn{
     position: absolute;
     background: #bbbbbb;
     height: 432px;
     left: 0%;
     width: 200px;
     z-index: 10;
     font-size: 40px;
     color: #fff;
     opacity: 0;
     cursor: pointer;
     text-align: center;
    }
    #prevBtn:hover{
     opacity: 0.2;
     
    }
    
    #nextBtn{
     position: absolute;
     background: #bbbbbb;
     height: 432px;
     right: 0%;
     width: 200px;
     z-index: 10;
     font-size: 40px;
     color: #fff;
     opacity: 0;
     cursor: pointer;
     text-align: center;
    }
    #nextBtn:hover{
     opacity: 0.2;
    }
    
    #lupa{
     height: 432px;
     width: 368px;
     background: #bbbbbb;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 10;
     right: 200px;
     font-size: 40px;
     color: white;
     opacity: 0;
     cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    #lupa:hover{
     opacity: 0.2;
    }
    
    #main{ width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; }
    
    #appear_image_div{
     width: 100%; height: 183%;
     position: abosolute;
     z-index: 15;
     opacity:0.9;
     background: black;
    }
    
    #appear_image{ 
     position: fixed;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     z-index: 16;
     border-radius: 18px;
    }
    
    #close{ 
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 92%;
     left: 95%;
     z-index: 16;
     border-radius: 18px;
     font-size: 40px;
     color: #dedede;
     opacity: 1;
     cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="titulointro" style="display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
     <h3 style="margin-top: 70px; margin-bottom: 0px; color: white; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 400; font-size: 30px; font-family: FuturaMediumBT; Arial; Helvetica; sans-serif;">
     Projetos de marketing</h3>
     <span style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 30px; width: 30px; border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb5b5; background: #fff;"></span>     
    </div>
     <div class="slideC" style="box-shadow: 0px 6px #48337a;border-radius: 15px;">
      <div id="prevBtn">
      <i class="fas fa-arrow-left" style="margin-top: 197px;"></i>
      </div>
      <div id="nextBtn">
      <i class="fas fa-arrow-right" style="margin-top: 197px;"></i>
      </div>
      <div id="lupa">
      <i class="fas fa-search-plus" style="margin-top: 197px;"></i>
      </div>
      <div id="fotos" class="slide">
      <img src="4.jpg" id="uClone" width="768" height="432" style="min-width: 768"></img>
      <img src="1.jpg" id="img1" width="768" height="432" style="min-width: 768"></img>
      <img src="2.jpg" id="img2" width="768" height="432" style="min-width: 768"></img>
      <img src="3.jpg" id="img3" width="768" height="432" style="min-width: 768"></img>
      <img src="4.jpg" id="img4" width="768" height="432" style="min-width: 768"></img>
      <img src="1.jpg" id="pClone" width="768" height="432" style="min-width: 768"></img>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're going to have to provide us with the relevant HTML and CSS so we can replicate your issue and provide you with an answer. We have no idea what `slideS` and `slideC` are.

Comment: And, did you open the browser's developer tools and look at the Console? It's most likely telling you what the problem is.

Comment: the IE console is blank, im going to put the html and css, just a sec

Comment: updated with the variables, html and css

Comment: When I run it in IE, I get a `Script Error` in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES6 syntax (let, const, arrow functions, etc.) do not work in IE. Try changing

```js
let counter = 1;
const size = slideC.offsetWidth;
```

To:

```js
var counter = 1;
var size = slideC.offsetWidth;
```

Also, in your `addEventListener`s you're using arrow functions. Those are also from ES6, so e.g. instead of

```js
nextBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
 if (counter >= slideImg.length - 1) return;
 slideS.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
 counter = counter + 1;
 slideS.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
 });
```

Use

```js
nextBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
 if (counter >= slideImg.length - 1) return;
 slideS.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
 counter = counter + 1;
 slideS.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
 });
```

Comment: thanks for the tip. Changed everything to var, but it's still not working.

Comment: @Lerio What is the error in the console? It's likely you're using some other ES6 syntax somewhere.

Comment: @Lerio In your code you're also using arrow functions. Check out my updated answer.